# problemas con funcionamiento de Windows forms (navegar entre ventanas)

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día, espero que estén bien el día de hoy.
Lo que pasa es que he terminado un proyecto en windows forms, y solo lo que me faltaba era programar el flujo del programa (conectar las ventanas)y lo que pasa es que en vez de cambiar de ventana, el programa se cierra... El código es reutilizado de otro proyecto en la cual funciona perfectamente el código.
¿Saben que puede ser? Incluso los 2 proyectos tienen la misma versión de .net (4,6).

Este código es del proyecto donde no funciona correctamente

```
private void btnEditTurno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormConsultarTurnos formToConT = new FormConsultarTurnos();
            formToConT.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Y este es el código del otro proyecto donde si funciona.

```
private void btnToHisto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormHisto formHistorico = new FormHisto();
    formHistorico.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

¿Hay alguna configuración de los formularios que no permite que se ejecute de forma correcta? Gracias por leer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que todo esto lo ejecutas desde el formulario principal, entonces al ejecutar this.close() cierras el formulario principal por lo que cierras el programa, utiliza this.Hide() para ocultarlo y no cerrar el programa:

```
private void btnEditTurno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormConsultarTurnos formToConT = new FormConsultarTurnos();
        formToConT.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }



 private void btnToHisto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormHisto formHistorico = new FormHisto();
        formHistorico.Show();
        this.Hide();
      }
```

Cuando cierres los formularios que abres deberás volver a hacer visible el form1

```
  this.close();
  form1.Visible = true;
```

O si quieres cerrar la aplicación en otro form que no sea el principal deberás llamar a

```
    Aplicación.Exit();
```

Comment: Pero si hago eso, cuando pase de uan ventana a otra, y le de en cerrar el formulario (la X de salir) No se cerraría el programa del todo?

Comment: Si es el formulario principal si, si no no, solo se cerraría ese formulario y el programa se quedaría corriendo con el form1 corriendo (visible=false) a no ser que llames a form1.visible=true  o llames a aplicación.exit() en el formClosing()